# Laravel Mix Build Successful but no changes sass

Tags: laravel, sass, laravel-5.5, laravel-mix

I'm trying to change the color theme of bootstrap with sass. I'm running the command ***npm run watch*** and when I save it does in prompt me with:

> Laravel Mix Build Successful

When I view my page I do not see the changes. (I've cleared cache and hard refreshed as well as closed broswer/new browser) To do this I'm updating "warning" to be a purplish color, but bg-warning is not changing to a purplish background (I believe this is what is intended).

I'm using Laravel framework 5.5

Here is my webpack.mix.js
[image]

Here is my app.scss
[image]

Here is my base/_colors.scss
[image]

I've tried throwing my base/_colors.scss code straight into the app.scss file with no luck either. (Even though it says it builds properly.)

I've also tried running the following with no success:

> npm run dev
>
> npm run production

**Edit:** the other possibility is this is not how sass works with bootstrap. Do I need to actually assign things the color of $warning or does this look for all instances of $warning (.alert-warning, .bg-warning, etc.) and replace?

Answer (score 1):

Try running npm hot, that helped me:

`npm run hot`

Comment: Could you add more details, for example, what exact version is working and why?

Comment: Sorry @Deiv, the command was npm run hot, I thought the one that helped me was updating it, already edited

Comment: you can also try to add --watch-poll

Comment: other thing I tried that seems helpful is closing the console and re run the commands

Answer (score 0):

I would do following further steps:

1. check if the folder base really exists
2. create a a new css file which in not inside a folder (base) just to check that that does not cause an error
3. Write simple css in your _colors.css and check if that works
4. add an !important statement after your color declaration to check if it does not have to do anything relating overriding the styling